# get value from listview not by position

Tags: android, listview

maybe its easy but im getting hard to solve this. So i have item in list view, the following code is:

```
private List<Item> loadItem(){

    itemEntityList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item item1 = new Item();
    item1.setId(1);
    item1.setCategoryId(1);
    item1.setProductName("Blopress 8mg");
    item1.setPrice("10000");
    itemEntityList.add(item1);

    Item item2 = new Item();
    item2.setId(2);
    item2.setCategoryId(3);
    item2.setProductName("Blopress 16mg");
    item2.setPrice("12000");
    itemEntityList.add(item2);

    Item item3 = new Item();
    item3.setId(3);
    item3.setCategoryId(2);
    item3.setProductName("Celebrex 100mg");
    item3.setPrice("15000");
    itemEntityList.add(item3);

    Item item4 = new Item();
    item4.setId(4);
    item4.setCategoryId(1);
    item4.setProductName("Celebrex 200mg");
    item4.setPrice("17000");
    itemEntityList.add(item4);

return itemEntityList;
}
```

I want when i click on list view its toast message Id. I have try this but its toast position of listview. what i want its toast Id not position, any advice?

```
    listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {


            Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity2.this, position+" _", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: What kind of Adapter are you using ?

Comment: can you see the last parameter of `onItemClick` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt i use ArrayList

Comment: @pskink how can i see id?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `getItemId()` method in your adapter. something like this:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position).getId();
}
```

if you have implemented this method like this in your adapter. you can call it whenever you want and get id of your item like this:

```
yourAdapter.getItemId(position);
```

UPDATE
as @pskink mentioned you can use the last parameter of `onItemClick`

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {...}
```

which is id.

Comment: upvote, you dont even need to call `getItemId`, just use the last parameter of `onItemClick`

Comment: @pskink yes of course. id is passed in onItemClick ;)